# how to keep angular reactive form

Tags: angular, ngxs

im using angular reactive form .i want to keep form data after leave component using ngxs form plugin.

my form :

```
travelerForm: FormGroup;

this.travelerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      toppings: ['', Validators.required],
      accept: [true, Validators.requiredTrue],
    });
```

my state code :

```
import { Action, State, Store, Selector } from '@ngxs/store';
import { SubmitTravelerForm } from '../actions/travelers.action';

​
@State<any>({
  name: 'traveler',
  defaults: {
    travelerForm: {
      model: undefined,
      dirty: true,
      status: '',
      errors: {}
    }
  }
})
export class TravelerState {
  @Action(SubmitTravelerForm)
  submitForm({getState}){
    console.warn(getState().travelerForm);


  }
constructor(private store: Store) {}
  @Selector() static travelerForm(state: any) {
    return state.travelerForm;
}

}
```

my action code :

```
export class SubmitTravelerForm {
    static readonly type = '[Traveler] Submit Form';
  }
```

my html code :

```
<form [formGroup]="travelerForm" novalidate ngxsForm="traveler.travelerForm" ngxsFormClearOnDestroy="false" (ngSubmit)="onSaveAndContinue()">
    <input type="text" formControlName="toppings">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="accept" id="accept"><label for="accept">I accept your terms</label>
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
  </form>
```

and my onSaveAndContinue() method :

```
this.store.dispatch(new SubmitTravelerForm());


    this.router.navigate(['../payment/confirm'], {
      queryParams: {
        source: this.source,

      }
    });
```

how can i get submit form value and bind to my form for keep form data value after leave component and come back

Comment: The bug in your code here is that you are setting the ngxsFormClearOnDestroy boolean attribute to the string "false". Any string with characters would be seen as truthy.
The correct way to have expressed this is as `[ngxsFormClearOnDestroy]="false"`.
In this way angular will evaluate the "false" expression as boolean `false`.
This is fixed in NGXS 3.7, where it can interpret non-boolean values (@bangash submitted a PR to fix it for you! ).

Answer (score 0):

Remove ngxsFormClearOnDestroy="false" so data will be there once you return [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-forms-plugin-simple-example-k48lks?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform.component.ts).

Comment: ngxsFormClearOnDestroy="false" and ngxsFormClearOnDestroy="true" treat is same i think it face the false as string so it alaway will be true

Answer (score -1):

given that http://ngxs.io say : 
In addition to these issues, there are workflows where you want to fill out a form and leave and then come back and resume your current status
but how?
someone has a solution?

Comment: Good question, but sorry, this is not an answer at all.